# .htaccess Rewrite %2f

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^reviews/area/Santa-Barbara%2F$"/reviews/area/santa-barbara" [R=301,NC,L]
```

I have the AllowEncodedSlashes directive on but the rewrite is still not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `"` from rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first use [`AllowEncodedSlashes` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) inside server config and set it to:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Then inside your root .htaccess you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(reviews/area/Santa-Barbara)\%2f$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```